# Load multiple workbooks(and filtering) into a same sheet excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

i am trying to load multiple workbook into the same sheet,  these workbooks will all contain one common column header. After i load multiple workbook, i would like to search for the rows i wanted and paste it onto a new sheet.

so far i have done the search and paste part but the part that requires to load multiple workbook is quite tough, can anyone help me out on this? thanks.

```
Sub SearchRowAndCopy()
Dim strSearch 
strSearch = Application.InputBox("Please enter the search string")
x = 2
Do While Cells(x, 1) <> ""
If Cells(x, 2) Like "*" & strSearch & "*" Then
Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(x).Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(erow)
End If
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
x = x + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use `Dir(folderPath & "*.xls*")` to get all the workbooks in a given folder, and `Workbooks.Open()` to load each one into Excel. Or is it the copying you're having a problem with?

Comment: @TimWilliams no, i am trying to extract the data from each of the workbooks i've selected and compile them into one sheet, sorry if i didnt make myself clear..

Comment: Selected how?   Are they already open?

Comment: @TimWilliams no they are not open, but they are all in the same folder

Comment: That goes back to my original suggestion.

Comment: @TimWilliams sorry, my vba isn't very good, how do i implement those two lines to my codes above?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub GetFiles()
    Dim fPath As String
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    fPath = "D:\Analysis\"

    sFile = Dir(fPath & "*.xls*")

    Do While Len(sFile) > 0
        Debug.Print fPath & sFile
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFile, ReadOnly:=True)
        '...
        'do your copying
        '...
        wb.Close False
        sFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```